# Using generic class as property of non-generic class C#

Tags: c#, generics

Say I have the following two classes, which ideally do what I want:

**Foo.cs:**

```
public class Foo
{
    private int Type { get; set; } = 0;

    public FooHelper FooHelper
    {
        get
        {
            switch (Type)
            {
                case 1:
                    return new FooHelper<Guid>("Foo", "Bar", "foobar", "", Guid.NewGuid());
                case 2:
                default:
                    return new FooHelper<int>("Bar", "Foo", "", "", 11);
            }
        }
    }

    public Foo(int type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }
}
```

**FooHelper.cs:**

```
public class FooHelper<T> where T : struct
{
    public string Controller { get; set; }    = string.Empty;
    public string Action { get; set; }        = string.Empty;
    public string Area { get; set; }          = string.Empty;
    public string NameParameter { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public T IdParameter { get; set; }        = default(T);

    public FooHelper() { }
    public FooHelper(string controller, string action, string area, string name, T id)
    {
        Controller    = controller;
        Action        = action;
        Area          = area;
        NameParameter = name;
        IdParameter   = id;
    }
}
```

Depending on the integer value passed in as parameter for the constructor of non-generic class **Foo**, the property FooHelper returns a new instance of the generic class **FooHelper** based on either a Guid or an int.

However, I cannot seem to make this work without making **Foo** also generic, which I don't want. The error I'm getting is on the property line of FooHelper, stating:

`Using the generic type 'FooHelper<T>' requires 1 type arguments`

which makes sense, but which I don't know at that point. I want to determine the type of **FooHelper** inside the constructor of **Foo**.

Am I missing something or is it just not possible to do what I want in this case?

Comment: I do not see any 'ProfileHelper<T>'

Comment: are you aware that your generic class has constraint on  T? (`where T: struct`)?

Comment: This is not really relevant to op's question as it isn't any problem as of right now with his code @RomanAnanyev

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that public `FooHelper FooHelper` won´t even compile because there is no type called `FooHelper`. However there are `FooHelper<int>` and `FooHelper<Guid>` which however don´t have anything in common. Thus this porblem is (again) caused by the fact that you supply an information (the type-switch) at runtime and expect the compiler to infer the right generic type at compile-time, which isn´t possible.

What you can do instead is create a non-generic interface from that all your helpers derive and which your method returns:

```
public interface IFooHelper { ... }
public class FooHelper<T> : IFooHelper where T : struct { ... }
```

Now within your `Foo`-class:

```
public IFooHelper FooHelper
{
    get
    {
        switch (Type)
        {
            case 1:
                return new FooHelper<Guid>("Foo", "Bar", "foobar", "", Guid.NewGuid());
            case 2:
            default:
                return new FooHelper<int>("Bar", "Foo", "", "", 11);
        }
    }
}
```

However as mentioned above during compile-time there is no way to know what the actual generic type-parameter actually is, because that type doesn´t even exist.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it. That makes total sense. I guess I will have to work around it, since the interface solution isn't quite workable either (as in: the generic type-parameter isn't accessible from the interface property).